# How to make unique groups into MUI's Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using MUI's Autocomplete to group my suggestions inside of search Bar.
I think it seems to be simple but not .
Firstly please look at the shape of my data

```
[{ 
"id" : 1,
"bookName" : "it starts with us",
"author" : "Colin Hoover"
},
{ "id" : 2,
"bookName" : "it ends with us",
"author" : "Colin Hoover"
},
{ "id" : 3,
"bookName" : "The great Gatsby",
"author" : "Scott Fitzgerald"
},
{ "id" : 4,
"bookName" : "To Kill a mocking bird",
"author" : "Harper Lee"
},
{ "id" : 5,
"bookName" : "Remainders of Him",
"author" : "Colin Hoover"
}, ... ]
```

now you can see, there are 3 books written by `'Colin Hoover'`, placed at different Ids. What I want to achieve is, my MUI's autocomplete should render

```
 Colin Hoover //author name as heading and books underneath it
     Remainders of Him 
     It Ends with us
     It starts with us 
     ... other books from this specific author
```

into my groupBy attribute in `MUI's Autocomplete`.

`Issue I am having now` - When I arrange the books which are meant for a certain author in consecutive Id's (say, id: 1, 2, 3, 4 ..) , the group-by of autocomplete works fine (i.e, it groups the different books under the same author if the author occurs at consecutive ids). But, when I arrange them in random fashion ( ie, id 1,3, 5, 8, 9 ..occupies books under same name "Colin Hoover"), then it doesn't group any of it rather it creates duplicate headers as "Colin Hoover" into autosuggestion list, which I don't want.

ALl I want is same header and all of his/her written books under his name into MUI's autocomplete.

Here's my Code

```
imports ...

export default function JobSearch () {
const [ books, setBooks ] = useState<Book[]>([]);
const [ searchTerm, setSearchTerm ] = useState<string>('');
// using redux
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
const { status } = useAppSelector ( state => state.menu );

useEffect(() => {
    agent.Books.getBooks() // my endpoint for getting the books
    .then((books) => { setBooks(books);
                       console.log(books)})
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
}, []);

const suggestions = books.map((book) => {
const bookDetail = `${book.name} by ${book.author}`
return {
    bookDetail,
    ...book
}});

const handleChangeInput = ( event : any ) => {
 setSearchTerm( event.target.value);
 console.log(event.target.value);
}


    return (
        <Fragment>
           <Autocomplete
             open = { status.name === "autoCompleteMenu" && status.open }
             autoHighlight = {true}
             autoComplete = {true}
             noOptionsText = {`Search for ${searchTerm}`}
             onOpen = { () => {
                dispatch(setOpenMenu("autoCompleteMenu"));
            }}
             onClose = { () => dispatch(setCloseMenu("autoCompleteMenu"))}
             options = {suggestions.sort((a, b) => -b.bookDetail.localeCompare(a.bookDetail))} 
             isOptionEqualToValue = {(option, value) => option.bookDetail === value.bookDetail}
             groupBy = {(option) => option.author} // I want all books sorted under same author
             getOptionLabel={(option) => option.bookDetail}
             renderInput = {(params) => (
                <TextField { ...params} 
                 label = {'search ...'}
                 onChange = {handleChangeInput}
                 variant = {'outlined'} />  )} />
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

I know I have to implement 'sort' into groupBy, but how to do the same, so as to sort all the books according to the author name and pass it as a parameter of the groupBy attribute.

All Suggestions are welcome and highly appreciated.